# How can I download the right printer driver for my new Epson ET-4810 with ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, epson

I am looking for VERY detailled help with the installation, because I have never done such a thing before...

Comment: Epson 4800-series printers should not require "printer drivers" at all. They speak IPP, a standard that does not need those pesky drivers at all. Connect to the printer using the Printers application.

Comment: First, try printing. The printer should be automatically recognized. If it does not work, try googling. I found [this tutorial](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2022/04/05/printer-epson-et-4850-ubuntu-22-04-installation-step-by-step/) for example. Try it and [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1496912/edit) with details like what you did and exact error messages you got at which step.

Answer (score 2):

Look for the Desktop Search icon on your dock or shortcut bar.

[image]

Click it.

Your Desktop Search screen will open. At the top of the screen is a Search box. Start typing "printers"

[image]

Click on the Printers application. A new window will open.

[image]

Click on Add.

Follow the prompts to add your printer.

- Most new printers don't require drivers anymore. Use the hardware database at http://openprinting.org to check if your printer requires a driver to be compatible with Ubuntu.